# CSS style text is not working as expected

Tags: html, css

Hi i just started using CSS i found this style which looks simple to do so i thought why not try making it to learn how to use CSS better,

But of course i failed badly basically am trying to make the style like this cause it looks like a simple thing to do right?

Result wanted:
[image: Wanted style]

My result:
[image: My Style]

Failed badly i know can anyone show me how to do the text position and stuff?

Thank you very much.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJGaeBPpPWONWkvBvhN3GcQxb_RVoIyAY7AxKuUuKFf0LFNkAUFVbuAZmEUtihSS0de0zFDx9v"/>
        <h3><a href="index.html">Jetliner with 155 on board loses chassis during takeoff in Russia</a></h3>
        <span>Pravda - </span><span>Mar 9, 2016</span>
        <p>A Boeing 737-400 en route Tyumen-Novy Urengoy lost chassis during takeoff on March 9 in Russia. Representatives of Yamal airline told ...</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
        <h3><a href="index.html">How Much Should You Spend on College and Student Loans?</a></h3>
        <span>Black Enterprise - </span><span>Apr 20, 2016</span>
        <p>The National Center for Education Statistics has a website that can help you calculate costs. CNN Money's College Cost Calculator is a great ...</p>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Style code:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: white;
    }
    ul
    {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .menu ul li
    {
        margin: 15px;
    }

    img
    {
        vertical-align: middle; /* | top | bottom */
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
    }
    .menu ul li h3{
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .menu ul li span{
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .menu ul li p
    {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: bottom; /* | top | bottom */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You can inspect the element in your browser and try to find out the code. Check and uncheck different css styling in page inspector to find out which styling provides what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try somtehing like this

```css
#container{
  width: 500px;
 height: 200px;
 
}
#imgContainer{
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  float:left;
  
}
#imgContainer img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#textContainer{
padding:12px;
float: left;
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">
   <div id="imgContainer"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/" alt=""></div>
 <div id="textContainer">
     <h2>Hello world this is some text </h2>
     <p> and here is some smaller text </p>
 </div>
  
 </div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Might sound harsh, but if you start with deleting all css you got, and give your image `float:left;` and move it to the bottom of the `li` might get you on your way.
goodluck

Answer (score 0):

You could put the element within the `<li>` into a `<section>` and apply the styles as in this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xwaLsd8p/)

```
      <ul>
    <li>
      <section>
        <div class="left">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJGaeBPpPWONWkvBvhN3GcQxb_RVoIyAY7AxKuUuKFf0LFNkAUFVbuAZmEUtihSS0de0zFDx9v" />
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <h3><a href="index.html">Jetliner with 155 on board loses chassis during takeoff in Russia</a></h3>
          <span>Pravda - </span><span>Mar 9, 2016</span>
          <p>A Boeing 737-400 en route Tyumen-Novy Urengoy lost chassis during takeoff on March 9 in Russia. Representatives of Yamal airline told ...</p>
        </div>

      </section>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

See modifications to your original code:

https://jsfiddle.net/xwaLsd8p/